# How to place an icon in a place where I click using Autodesk Service Platform?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

When I click on an object, I want an icon to be placed where I clicked.
How can I achieve it?

This sample uses dbid and the position of an icon is the center of the object of the dbid, not the place where I click.
https://adndevblog.typepad.com/technology_perspective/2020/12/forge-viewer-markup-along-dbid.html

Also, this sample is close to what I want to achieve, but is too old and not helpful
https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/high-performance-3d-markups-pointcloud-forge-viewer

What I want to know is

- how to calculate clicked positions
- how to set icon in the clicked place
- how to implement occlusion

Any help?

---

UPDATE

`clientToWorld(x, y, ignoreTransparent)`

This works out to set icon in the clicked place

[Forge Viewer: How to convert arbitrary client point to world point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53511258/forge-viewer-how-to-convert-arbitrary-client-point-to-world-point)

Answer (score 0):

> How to calculate clicked positions

As you already found, doing a hit test for specific viewport XY coordinates can be done using the `clientToWorld` method.

> how to set icon in the clicked place

> how to implement occlusion

There are different ways.

For example, you could overlay an HTML element (for example, `<svg>` or `<img>`) with your icon on top of the 3D viewport, and use the Viewer API to control its position by projecting 3D scene coordinates back to 2D viewport coordinates. You can see how we do this in one of our code samples [here](https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-digital-twin/blob/develop/public/scripts/extensions/issues.js#L100). Unfortunately with this approach the overlaid graphics will never be occluded by the 3D content.

Another approach would be to insert custom three.js geometry (e.g., `THREE.PointCloud` or `THREE.Plane`) into the 3D scene ([blog](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/custom-models-forge-viewer)), and apply the icon image to the mesh as a texture.

Comment: Using PointCloud, can you occlude the the overlaid graphics? In addition, do you know sample codes with the current version Autodesk Viewer, not old one?

Comment: Yes, PointCloud content can be occluded by other geometries in the scene. I'm not sure if we have a more up-to-date blog post on that. Is something in the old blog post not working? If so, let us know and we'll look at that,.

Comment: Ok! I'll try the code in the blog post when using PointCloud approach.